# Connected Component testing with certain prop (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I have a react component with Redux @connect decorator, for instance:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@connect(mapStateToProps, 
{
    onPress: () => {...code}) // Component receives this func, not passed from the test
} 
export class Component extends Component {
    render () {
        return <button onclick={this.props.onPress>....</button> 
    }
}
```

I faced with a problem that mocked functions passed to the component in a test file are not passed into the component:

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({name: reducer})
);
const ComponentConnected = connect(..., {
    onPress: {jest.fn()} // Component doesn't receive this mock
})(() =>(<Component />));

describe('Component testing', () => {
    it('should render component', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ComponentConnected />
            </Provider>
        );
        expect(wrapper.find(Component)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

Also, I tried to pass the mock function as a tested component prop, it didn't help too. Is it possible to solve this problem without re-writing component @connect decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to pass a prop to a connected Component. I used shallow, dive and setProps enzyme methods:

```
describe('Component testing', () => {
    it('should render component', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ComponentConnected />
            </Provider>
        );
        const connectedComponentWrapper = wrapper.dive().dive();
        connectedComponentWrapper.setProps({anyProp: 'anyProp'});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, instead of mocking connect function of redux-connect. You should mock the action itself. replace `../actions` with your actions file.

```
import { onPress } from "../actions";
jest.mock("../actions");

onPress.mockReturnValue({ someval: 1 });
```